# Joint Model, Time-Dependent Endogenous Covariate in Longitudinal Submodel

Tags: mixed-model, survival, random-effects-model, endogeneity

Let us say we have a joint model whose hazard function (survival submodel) at a given time point $t$ is given by:

$$
h_{i}\left(t \mid \mathcal{M}_{i}(t), w_{i}\right) =  h_{0}(t) \exp \left\{\gamma^{\top} w_{i}+\alpha m_{i}(t)\right\}, \quad t>0
$$

with $w_{i}$ being a vector of time-independent survival covariates, $m_{i}(t)$ the value of an endogenous longitdunal marker, which is only measured at discrete time points $j=1, \ldots, n_{i}$, and $\alpha$ being the association parameter that measures the strength of the assocation between the survival submodel and the longitudinal part.

Since the joint likelihood involves the cumulative hazard function $\mathcal{H}(t)$,  one requires $\mathcal{M}_{i}(t)$, the full covariate history of the longitudinal marker $m_{i}(t)$. This can be obtained by means of the longitudinal submodel, which is given by:

$$
\begin{aligned}
y_{i}(t) &=m_{i}(t)+\varepsilon_{i}(t) \\[10pt]
m_{i}(t) &=x_{i}^{\top}(t) \beta+z_{i}^{\top}(t) b_{i} \\[10pt]
b_{i} & \sim \mathcal{N}(0, D), \quad \varepsilon_{i}(t) \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \sigma^{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$

Here, $y_{i}$ is the vector of the measured values of the longitudinal marker. The measurements are, however, usually not completely accurate, but are prone to random i.i.d. errors $\varepsilon_{i}(t)$. We are thus rather interested in the true, uncontaminated values $m_{i}(t)$. $x_i$ and $z_i$ are the  design vectors for the possibly time dependent fixed- and random-effect variables, respectively,

In all the examples I have seen in Rizopoulos' book, these time-dependet variables were functions of time itself. Since the passing of time is a predictable process, they can thus be seen as exogenous variables. What happens however, if we add a time-dependet variable, which is not a predictable process? For example, we could add a time-dependent biomarker $v_i(t)$, which itself is only measured at discrete time points, so that we obtain

$$
m_{i}(t)=x_{i}^{\top}(t) \beta+z_{i}^{\top}(t) b_{i} + v_{i}^{\top}(t)\theta
$$

My questions would be:

1. Is this scenario actually of any practical relevance?
2. If yes, how would one now go about reconstruncting the continuous marker history $\mathcal{M}_{i}(t)$?